# How to exclude specific file types from the following .htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-type

How can you exclude specific files types (xml and txt) from the following rewrite rule?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(xml|txt)$
```

Comment: Each rewrite condition only applies for the following Rewrite rule I think.

Comment: The RewriteCond needs to be atop of the RewriteRule where it is suppose to work with. Taking this htaccess example here, it would be after `RewriteBase /`

Comment: is there a quick way to make this apply to all files? i dont want the rule to trigger at all if the url contains any file extension

Comment: If you exclude this for all files, it won't trigger on anything. Do you mean all file with extension? all files that are not `*.php` ?