# urls to other files after rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess file I rewrite all URLs to my index file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?string=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So far, so good. When I request the url `example.com/path/to/my/page` the value of `$_GET['string']` is path/to/my/page, as it should be.

Now the problem:
in my index.php I use several script/css files like this:
    `<script src="script/script.js"></script>`

With these rewrite rules on, the script/css files get requested as `example.com/path/to/my/script/script.js`.

Is there a way to make sure the script gets requested without the /path/to/my part?

The only solution I found is putting the entire url in the src attribute, but I don't like it that way.

Note: the path part can consist of a variable number of parts, so /long/path/to/another/page or /page are also possible URLs.

Comment: Exclude file types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494542/how-to-exclude-specific-file-types-from-the-following-htaccess-rewrite-rule

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Nope, doesn't work. I get a 404 on those files.

Comment: Use absolute URLs "/script/script.js" for example. This assume the script directory is in your root folder and not moving around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add a relative URL base to the header of your index.php file:

```
<base href="/" />
```