# Exclude 2 png images from htaccess rule

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule in my htaccess that redirects all of my non-slash URL to slash url. However I'd like to exclude 2 .png URLs which for some reason are affected by this rule.

It ads a slash to some .png images such as http://agora.encreation.com/wp-content/uploads/portfolio-immobiliere-pujol-thumb.jpg

But there are other images who don't have this issue such as http://agora.encreation.com/wp-content/uploads/portfolio-thumb-alliance.jpg

So basically I'd like to exclude .png and .jpg URLs from the rule adding the slashes.

Here is my htaccess :

```html
# Ensure all URLs have a trailing slash.
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://agora.encreation.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks

Florian

Comment: Looks like you're already doing that with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$`. That excludes anything that has a dot towards the end. Alternately use something like `!\.(jpg|png)$` to be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude specific file types from the following .htaccess rewrite rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494542/how-to-exclude-specific-file-types-from-the-following-htaccess-rewrite-rule)

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

already takes care of *existing* images. The first mentioned URL `.../portfolio-immobiliere-pujol-thumb.jpg` is redirected, because it doesn't exist. The second one `.../portfolio-thumb-alliance.jpg` is not affected, because it is an existing image, and so excluded by the rewrite condition.

To exclude all image requests, no matter if the corresponding files exist or not, you must add another condition as @Eamonn already suggested, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png)$ [NC]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did the trick!